# Rendering Bitmap goes out of memory in WPF (Out of memory exception)

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

Framework : .NET 3.5
Technology: WPF

While using RenderTargetBitmap.Render(Canvas), the canvas contains roughly 40-50 images. The rendering says OutOfMemoryException. Any possible resolution available?

I'm aware of CachedComposition from .NET 4.0, but since this is a lower framework - any equivalents available?

Comment: You should provide some code if you need help. At least the XAML of your canvas and the C# you use for rendering.

Comment: I understand that. But I'm not at liberty to share the code. Sorry for that. Besides, If you're aware of any CachedComposition equivalents on .NET 3.5 - you're free to share.

Comment: What is the average size of the images ?

Comment: Feel at least free to say which line of code (what method) throws the exception. If you simply say OutOfMemoryException, that could also come from an infinite loop creating new double[10,10,10] in the background.

Comment: Phil, the exception is exactly from "RenderTargetBitmap.Render(Canvas)" Here, Canvas is the Canvas object containing the images

Comment: Sorry, did not see that. How large is your canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your canvas's size is too large or dpiX/dpiY used to render is over an acceptable threshold (it depends on RAM capacity of your computer). The default dpi is 96.